# How to remove or fix the stain on this table?

Tags: wood, table

I think a harsh chemical remove the varnish on this table, how should I go about fixing it?

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you check out the [finishing] tag at [woodworking.se]. There is a _lot_ of info there. So much so that if you asked to get this migrated over there, it would probably be closed as a dupe.

Comment: The elephant in the room is ----   The Floor OR the DIY play land box on the table ?

Comment: There is probably no solution other than to cover it with paint or sand the surface down, re-stain, and apply a new coat of varnish.

Comment: It will take a refinishing of one sort or another, whether a re-amalgamation or stripping and refinishing with a compatible finish to match the original. I am sure the problem is with the finish, not into the wood. It may be a simple as a water stain if the finish is shellac or lacquer.

Comment: yup looks is unavoidable, is an easy DIY job?